# Hola a todos, intento redireccionar un formulario de login con PHP, en el servidor local funcionaba, pero en el servidor web no he podido lograrlo

Tags: php, submit

intento redireccionar un formulario de login  con PHP, en el servidor local funcionaba de maravilla, pero en el servidor web no he podido lograrlo

codigo php:

```
     <?php

     if (!empty ($_POST["btningresar"])) {
     if (empty ($_POST["correo"]) and empty($_POST["password"])) {
     echo "Campos vacios";

     } else {
     $correo=$_POST["correo"];
     $password=$_POST["password"];
     $sql=$conexion->query ("select * from usuarios where correo='$correo' and 
     password='$password'");
    if ($datos=$sql->fetch_object()) {
     header("location:orden.php");
     } else {
     echo "Acceso denegado";
     }
     }

     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Ojo a la inyección de código :)

Comment: Te muestra algún error?, la cabecera header o redirección debe ir antes de cualquier etiqueta HTML o JS, de lo contrario te marcara error, también recuerda agregar **exit() o die()** depues de la cabecera de redirección.